# Using ios storyboard in conjunction with multiple targets

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I've got a UITabBarController with 5 different viewcontrollers attached to it. My app consists of 2 targets, A and B. B is mostly the same as A but has less features (and thus less items to display on the tabbar). What I'm trying to do is use storyboard references to determine which viewcontrollers appear on the tabbar. So say I've got a viewcontroller A1 which is supposed to be visible in target A but not B. What I tried is moving A1 into a separate storyboard and setting that storyboard's target module to A. This however causes the main storyboard to complain that it can't find the new storyboard when I'm trying to compile module B.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible with storyboards?

Comment: How do you differentiate between these two modules? Are they two different targets in your project? Or only in your code?

Comment: @Sti Yes, they're two different targets.